# Can't with anybody/anyone neither and nor

Tags: pronouns, neither-nor

Is it correct to use *nor* in the following sentence?

> I can't touch anybody nor anyone.

Comment: Using "anyone" and "anybody" in the same sentence like this is rather tautological - that is, it is saying the same thing twice using different words that mean the same thing. Here, "anyone" and "anybody" mean the same thing. See http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/67741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect. You should not use *nor* after negative expressions. See *The Elements of Style*, by William Strunk Jr. and E.B. White, Macmillan, 1979, Chapter 4, page 53.

The following is correct:

> "I can't touch anybody **or** anyone".

Comment: Grammatically, Richard is quite right but as everyone else said, the question shouldn't arise because the vocabulary is tautological…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Robbie, thanks. I responded slightly prior to the other two respondents. What do you mean in this case by "the vocabulary is tautological"?

Comment: Oh… as others had noted, there is no relevant difference between "anybody" and "anyone"…

Comment: By the way, I've more than twice heard 'anyone or anything…' rather like 'no-one and nothing' which might have contributed to some confusion.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin To tell you the truth, I considered only the issue of using *nor* following a negative expression. I didn't consider whether the use of *anybody or anyone* constituted proper usage. I see nothing grammatically wrong with it, but at the same time, I agree with you that its "tautological* aspect is not good form. I too have heard, not infrequently, phrases such as *anyone or anything*; that particular phrase is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Better:

> I can't touch anybody or anyone.

Because:

[Not [A OR B] ]

But, "anybody or anyone" is redundant.

So, simply:

> I can't touch anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily repeating yourself. "anybody" and "anyone" are about the same. You only need one or the other indefinite pronoun in your Simple Sentence.

I | can | not | touch | anybody [:any person--Webster's.]

or

I | can | not | touch | anyone [:any person at all--Webster's.]

Both pronouns are singular. As an indefinite pronoun the pronoun does not refer to a definite person or thing; frequently used without an antecedent (the word the pronoun refers or stands for: Jane = antecedent; her = pronoun)